# Grails - How save params to controller from another controller

Tags: grails, parameter-passing

i have a specific question;

I'm newbie on grails i'm trying to write some test app with this scenario;

I have 2 Domain Classes

1- Car 
2- Registration

I want to add some cars with brand, model etc. And user will choose from list some car and click to rent car button. When user will click to rent car button will open the registration/create page here i want to get car:id of user selected car and user will enter some extra information from himself like Your Name and when user will click to save button on registration/list i need to see registrations with car:id and your name entry

In car class i have list of cars, with this field here is my car model;

```
package rentme

class Car {

    String brand
    String model
    String fuelType
    BigDecimal pricePerDay
    String busy

    static constraints = {
        brand(inList:["AUDI", "BMW", "MERCEDES", "NISSAN", "HONDA", "FORD"])
        model()
        fuelType(inList:["FUEL", "DIESEL", "AUTOGAS"])
        pricePerDay(min:0.0, max:1000.0)
        busy(inList:["YES", "NO"])

    }
}
```

And i have Registration class,

```
package rentme

class Registration {

    String yourName



    static constraints = {
        yourName()
    }
}
```

So what i did ,

i add the cars/index.gsp this link in g:each;

```
<g:each in="${carList}" var="car">
                    <p>${car.id} </p>
                    <g:link action="create" controller="registration" params="${[car: car, carId : car.id ]}">
                        Rent Car
                    </g:link>

                </g:each>
```

and modified Registration Controller like that;

```
 def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond Car.list(params), model:[carCount: Car.count()]
    }
```

Now what happened; When i click to rent button page redirect to registration/create page with the catching id which car user selected;

here is my registration/create.gsp

```
 <g:form action="save">
                <div><p>Car ID : ${car.id} </p></div>
                <fieldset class="form">
                    <f:all bean="registration"/>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="buttons">
                    <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
                </fieldset>
            </g:form>
```

And when fill your name field and click to save button everything is okey, So like it's working but not :)

because when i check the my db i don't see there selected car id.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM registration;
+----+---------+--------------+
| id | version | your_name    |
+----+---------+--------------+
| 12 |       0 | Cihan Zengin |
| 13 |       0 | Cihan        |
| 14 |       0 | ndlkdkldnkl  |
+----+---------+--------------+
```

But when i click to registration/index or registration/show there is have just your name value but i want to see there car:id too.

How to do that? Please someone tell me that because i can't understand and can't found nowhere something like that in internet

Comment: Not sure, but simply adding the car id in the `Registration` class might do the trick. Currently, the `Registration` class contains the name only, so that's what you get.

Comment: Just add like a field?  That time user should to select car id again in registration/create i don't want to do this, i want in registration/create after save registration class will save car id which i passed from car class.

Comment: You need to decide if a Registration belongs to a Car, or if a Car belongs to a Registration... Here's Car A, I want to register it to Bob. In that case, a Registration could be said to belong to Car.  So you would need annotations in your models to denote that fact, then adjust your controllers and views. Read up on Grails/Gorm with respect to hasOne and belongsTo.

Comment: @railsdog so how need to adjust controller and view? u can tell me please details with code?

Comment: There have been several questions on SO lately that are similar to yours. So I am reluctant to write code (assuming it is for an assignment). Far better to point the questioner to the reference docs than to write code (how else will one learn?). It is not hard, you just have to invest the effort.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume for every registration, there will only be one car and one person each.

Firstly, for the Registration class:

```
package rentme

class Registration {

    String yourName
    Car rentedCar

    static constraints = {
        yourName()
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have added Car inside, so for every registration object, there will be a Car object. In your database for Registration table, a new column 'CAR_ID" will be added automatically.

Next, for the cars/index.gsp each:

```
<g:each in="${carList}" var="car">
    <p>${car.id} </p>
    <g:link action="create" controller="registration" params="${[carId : car.id ]}">
        Rent Car
    </g:link>

</g:each>
```

The `action="create"` and `controller="registration"` means method `create()` in `registrationController` will be called, and if found or not found, registration/create.gsp will be rendered. In registrationController, i'm not sure what's your index method for, but just add these:

```
def create() {
    def selectedCar = Car.get(params.carId)

    [car: selectedCar]
}

def save() {
    def selectedCar = Car.get(params.carId)

    def registration = new Registration(
        yourName: params.yourName,
        car: selectedCar
    ).save()
}
```

Then, in registration/create.gsp:

```
<g:form action="save">
    <div><p>Car ID : ${car.id} </p></div>
    <fieldset class="form">
        <f:all bean="registration"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <input type="hidden" name="carId" id="carId" value="${car?.id}"/>
        <input type="text" name="yourName" required>
        <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
    </fieldset>
</g:form>
```

The create() method gets the params of carId from car/index.gsp and use it to get the Car object, and rendered in registration/create.gsp

The hidden field in registration/create.gsp ensure that the car id will be passed to the controller when the form is submitted. Therefore, when the submitButton is clicked, save() method in Registration Controller will be called and a Registration object with the retrieved Car Object will be saved.

There's a lot of bad practices in what we did here but it should work. Let me know if this is still not clear :)

Comment: Give a man a fish and he eats for one night, teach a man to fish and he eats for a lifetime.

Comment: I'm not sure about the others but back then when I know nothing, showing the codes actually help way better and faster than looking at reference pointed by others. It really helps to understand something from a perspective you understand, and then looking at the reference.

Comment: There is truth in that, but there are also numerous resources available that provide a broader scope of reference than the answer to a single, sometimes narrow question. Looking at what is created by a "grails generate-controller", or "grails generate-views", or "grails generate-all" goes a long way to showing the grails default perspective on convention over configuration. Then you extend from there.

Comment: @railsdog i'm a vegan dude so save fish for yourself :)

Comment: @Jay Thank u i understand from example code better how u say, i try your method but get this error,  URI
/registration/create
Class
java.lang.NullPointerException
Message
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.gsp.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: [views/registration/create.gsp:38] Error executing tag <g:form>: Error evaluating expression [car.id] on line [29]: Cannot get property 'id' on null object
Caused by
Cannot get property 'id' on null object

Comment: That means for some reason in create() function, def selectedCar = Car.get(params.carId) is null. Try to print out params.carId in that function to see if params.carId is null.

Comment: @Jay i tried to do like thaT but nothing happened.  def create() {
        respond new Registration(params)
        def selectedCar = Car.get(params.carId)

        [car: selectedCar]

        if  (Car == null)  {
            println "": " + params.Car.Id
        }
    }